# jsx:decode json into string value instead of binary

Tags: json, erlang, jsx

I read the doc of [`jsx`](https://github.com/talentdeficit/jsx) which removed the `post_decode` option because it prevented the evolution of the jsx.

So what's the option now if I want what `post_decode` can do. For example, I can have a function to convert binary value into string value with this option.

```
F = fun(E) when is_binary(E) -> binary_to_list(E) end,
jsx:decode(BinaryJsonString, [{post_decode,F}]).
```

How do I do that now?

Comment: You can consider using [ejson](https://github.com/jonasrichard/ejson) which still has this option.

Comment: Also you can do it yourself with what you get as return value, instead of injecting the function into jsx's API. Using return value seems to be clearer and more functional.

Comment: thank you. yes. I guess I can do that. Just wondering maybe it's something what jsx:decoder is there for. I didn't quite understand how to use it by reading the doc.